# the idea behind signal processing

Tags: signal-processing, dsp, algorithm

Is how we detect signals that we start the transceiver in a sampling period at a certain frequency and we take the convolution of it and all incoming signals during that period? When we transform we can check what the incoming signals were and discard if they aren't needed to be detected?

Comment: Unfortunately your question is incoherent and much too general. What signals? What trtansceiver? Why a sampling period which implies digital processing but signal processing applies to analog as well as digital techniques. Convolution is only one of many signal processing tools. You need to clarify your question and make it much more specific so that a reasonable answer can be formulated.

Comment: Hi Barry I know not a really great question.. I definitely was thinking of digital processing and a general purpose computer being used but your reply helps me formulate my thoughts better and are good questions I need to ask myself when I want to process a signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are saying appears to be partially right.

> Is how we detect signals that we start the transceiver in a sampling
> period at a certain frequency and we take the convolution of it and
> all incoming signals during that period?

What you are describing is sampling an analog signal with an A/D converter.  Once the signals are in digital form they can then be processed using digital signal processing methods.  But that's not the only way to do signal processing.  There are many other methods.

> When we transform we can check what the incoming signals were and
> discard if they aren't needed to be detected?

Once a signal is in digital form it is possible to convolve a it with a sine-wave (or other kernel) to select a particular frequency range or signal shape.  There are of course many other types of signal processing beyond just selecting one signal from some input data.

As an alternative to what you are proposing, analog electronics is also used for signal processing purposes.  For example, imagine an AM radio broadcast with a bandwidth of 100kHz, centered at 99MHz.

The first analog signal processing step would usually be to run that signal through an analog band pass filter to select only the signals in the range of 88.95MHz to 99.05MHz.

The next step would be to rectify the signal using a diode.

Finally the signal would be run through a low pass filter to reconstruct the audio signals from the AC peaks.

The above processing can be done with a few capacitors resistors diodes and possibly some transistors or op-amps.

Doing the same processing purely in digital would require an ADC running at least 200MHz and a CPU running probably near 1GHz.  Relatively speaking that would be a lot more expensive and power hungry.

When designing a system one needs to do analysis to determine when digital signal processing is appropriate.

Comment: What's the point of transmitting AM at 99 MHz? It's slap bang in the FM broadcast band and thus probably illegal.

Comment: Thank you I really appreciate the answer, these are the kind of things I am trying to understand, under what circumstances is it more appropriate to process it digitally or analog. I would like to be able to process any signal in any way.

Comment: @BrianDrummond It was just an example.  I am aware that 99MHz is in the FM radio bands in the USA.  AM radio is really easy to process so I chose that for the example.  I chose a 99MHz carrier because I wanted an example that was of sufficiently high frequency to illustrate that sometimes analog methods might be preferable.  Regular AM radio frequencies are in the 540 to 1600khz range.  The processing requirements at those frequencies would be much less and wouldn't illustrate the point as well.

Answer (score -1):

I once worked for years with the engineers who designed the NASA downlink telemetry equipment, from the RF signals to phase locking and word_locking and multiplexor_frame locking, to the myriad chart recorders displaying the realtime data on long rolls of paper.

They spoke of integrate_and_dump bit_recovery methods as being optimal for certain common scenarios of random noise, such as what the radio channels created.

These systems were 10 racks of equipment in size.

A flipflop was a cordwood module, about a cubic inch, with components (resistors, 2N706 transistors, diodes, capacitors to bring in the state_change pulse edges) placed between 2 PCBs of size 1" square.

The signal_recovery was

- discharge a capacitor
- allow that capacitor to charge in whatever direction is needed by the arriving bit energy, during that bit time
- when bit time ends, have a comparator decide "1" or "0", while another capacitor begins to store the energy of the next bit

Your tax dollars at work.

These people went on to design and build the "ARCNET" of Datapoint.

Similar people, in Silicon Valley, defined Ethernet circuitry.

=======================================

Follow up on Tony Stewart mention of "matched filter":

In the 20MHz bit_synchronizer I assisted in, we used the matched filters designed by Peter Halpern, who used the methods of "maximum likelihood" of Peter Mallory.

Halpern wrote about "trigonometric pulse forming networks" having NRZ and BIphase output ports.

Comment: I agree. I had access all of these in the 70’s when at Bristol Aerospace and later designed my own for another small company when we wanted an accurate data demodulator. I chose the integrate and dump with a matched filter (to the spectrum) as the only way to go. This uses all of the data and noise integrated in a small cap so that a CMOS switch can dump it in an insignificant amount of time after a comparator is latched by the PLL clock recovered from the data in phase sync.  This gives the ideal results down to the noise threshold with the ideal BER vs SNR theoretical curves published.

Comment: When the data rate is too high for Ron*C, one can alternate between two IDC ccts

Comment: Thank you for that analogsystemsrf. Reading this helps me piece a lot of concepts together. I am better understanding the different ways you can process a signal and what scenarios one implementation may be more suitable than another.